# Correct statistical significance test for "Choose between A or B"-questionnaire

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I want to determine if algorithm A is better than algorithm B by letting users vote on the solution of each algorithm.

Compared to a normal A/B Test, I do not show a random solution A or B to random users.
Instead, **I show every user the solution of algorithm A and B at the same time and make them pick their favourite.**

That way I control for the different inputs and "tastes" of each user, and both algorithms get a fair shot at every user/input pair. Every user may only participate once in this test.

I think therefore my samples are not independent and I need to take care of this.

However, **I do not know how this dependence is called and what test of significance would be appropriate** for it. Any ideas for such a test available in Python?

Thank you very much!

tl;dr:

- I show every user the solution of algorithm A and B at the same time and make them pick their favourite
- I do not know how this dependence is called and what test of significance would be appropriate

Comment: A useful search term is "one sample test of proportion."

Comment: Thank you, that was all I needed :-) For reference, I then found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53148935/one-sample-test-for-proportion