# Correct statistical significance test for “Choose between A or B”-questionnaire

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, proportion

I have seen similar questions to this one, but I did not get my answer.

My problem is similar to what is described here: [Correct statistical significance test for "Choose between A or B"-questionnaire](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/540020/correct-statistical-significance-test-for-choose-between-a-or-b-questionnaire)

I compare two algorithms A and B that generate two lists, and on a survey with several questions asking for various aspects, i.e., criteria, e.g., accuracy, value, trustworthiness, etc., users choose between A, B, or equal options.

I have five response options (A: -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 : B), so the response format is weighted for A and B. They are also paired, meaning their correlation is -1 if the scores are separated.

The main problem is the small sample size, with missing responses. For example, from a total of 20 users for criteria 1, the responses are 9 for B and 3 for A, 2 equals, and 6 missing (If I just take the response as yes, no, and equals, transforming score 2 to 1).

I searched a lot, I learned that I cannot use z-test because of the sample size. I read about binomial tests and proportion one-sample tests. But for such a sample size, I don't know yet which one to use. I really prefer a test that I can run in python.

This is the closest response I have found so far: [Question on basic hypothesis testing](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151334/question-on-basic-hypothesis-testing) But again, my issue is the sample size, which varies for various questions. For example, see below:

```
        System A preferred  System B preferred   A and B equally  missing   total 
criteria 1      9            3                     2                 6       20
criteria 1     10            4                     1                 4       20
.....
criteria 1      5            5                     1                 9       20
```

Please help me figure out what is the correct test to apply here?
I want to know if system A is ultimately better than B or not?

Comment: I’ll go ahead and suggest the obvious but often forgotten/ignored: you can get more data. Surveying more people will get around the sample size limitations better.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, that is not possible, as in most cases. These results are the result of a one-year-long study that each study participant had to use applications for a long time. If I could have repeated the study, the best solution was to redesign the survey. Here are some suggestions I found, but have no idea if they make sense because of the data: 1) to go for a binom anyway, 2) to rely on descriptive data

Comment: 3) to use some sort of simulation and show that it is better than random case based on inference statistics, but not sure how to do this exactly, and especially in python. I also read about non-parametric such as fisher exact, but don't think it applies here.

Comment: Can I add the missing values to both A preferred and B preferred equally? This way, I would have more than 10 successes and 10 failures in each case? Therefore, running a binomial model, I check if the p value is significant at 0.05 for both or not? If it is significant for both A and B, taken separately, I can conclude that the differences between them are non-significant. Otherwise, for example if the value is significant for A for instance and not B, then it is safe to assume that the choice A is preferred more than B significantly.